# Convert Calendar to XMLGregorianCalendar with specific formatting

Tags: java

I am having some issues in converting a calendar object to an XMLGregorian calendar in the format of `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`.

My current code is:

```
Calendar createDate = tRow.getBasic().getDateCreated(0).getSearchValue();
Date cDate = createDate.getTime();
GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
c.setTime(cDate);
XMLGregorianCalendar date2 = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(c);
```

which returns a date of `2013-01-03T11:50:00.000-05:00`.

I would like it to read `2013-01-03 11:50:00`.

I have checked a bunch of posts, which use DateFormat to parse a string representation of the date, however my dates are provided to me as a Calendar object, not a string.

I'd appreciate a nudge in the right direction to help me figure this one out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An XMLGregorianCalendar has a specific W3C string representation that you cannot change.

However, you can format a `Date` with `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String dateStr = dateFormat.format(cDate);
```

You can get a `Date` object from a `XMLGregorianCalendar` object as follows:

```
xmlCalendar.getGregorianCalendar().getDate()
```

Comment: I don't need to get a date from an XMLGregorianCalendar, but rather set it. The XMLGregorianCalendar is required by a receiving web service.

Comment: Right, if you want to format the date differently from the default then you need to use a `Date` object. You start with one of those, so you shouldn't need the XMLGregorianCalendar at all.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping I could avoid editing the generated classes from XMLGreg... to Date, but looks like I have to anyways

Comment: The XMLGregorianCalendar uses a W3C standard representation for dates. If the web service is under your control, a more elegant route might be to make it accept the standard. Otherwise SimpleDateFormat or Joda time looks like the way forward...

Comment: This isn't working for me. I have to declare the SimpleDateFormat as `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");` having a `'T'` in between, because the `XMLGregorianCalendar` expects it

Comment: Right, but the OP's question was about how to convert between a Gregorian date and a simpler format: `2013-01-03 11:50:00`.

Answer (score 1):

`DateFormat#format` takes a `Object` parameter. From memory, it should accept a `Calendar` object, if not, it WILL accept a `Date` object, so you could use `Calendar#getTime` as a worse case scenario

You can use a instance of [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to specify a custom formatting. This will ensure that the result is always the same for different systems

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this tutorial it may help?

http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaDateTimeAPI/article.html

Speicifcally this code is a good example:

```
// Format the output with leading zeros for days and month
SimpleDateFormat date_format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
System.out.println(date_format.format(cal1.getTime()));
```